# TypeError: 'Length' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask

I´m developing with Flask and It throws this error when I run the app. "TypeError: 'Length' object is not iterable"

I show the code:

```
class Formulario2(Form):
    username = TextField('Name', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    lastname = TextField('Lastname', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    DNI = TextField(
       'DNI', [validators.Length(min=9, max=9, message='Must be 9 characters')])
    #date =
    email = TextField(
        'Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35),
                  validators.Regexp(regex='\w+@(\w+)\.com|es',
                                    message='Dirección no válida')])
    adress = TextAreaField('Adress:',validators.Length(min=1,max=50))
    payment = RadioField('Payment:', choices=[('1','Option 1'), ('2','Option 2')])
    VISA = TextField(
        'VISA', [validators.Length(min=19, max=19),
                 validators.Regexp(regex='(\d{4}(-| )){3}\d{4}',
                                   message='Not valid')])
    password = PasswordField(
        'Password', [validators.Required(),
                     validators.Length(min=7),
                     validators.EqualTo('confirm',
                                        message='Password doesn´t match')])
    confirm = PasswordField('Repeat the password')
    accept_tos = BooleanField('Accept conditions', [validators.Required()])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adress = TextAreaField('Adress:',validators.Length(min=1,max=50))
```

You didn't include this `validators.Length` in a list.

Comment: It´s true. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SantiagodeDiego no problem. If this solved your problem, please consider [accepting my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)